Are there any parts of the US Constitution that state that the laws apply universally to all citizens?
I guess I did not know that US Presidents had any kind of criminal immunity or that it was legally possible for anyone to make a law that they did. I am curious if there is really nothing in the Constitution that says something like, “The laws apply to all US citizens”. I feel like that would be a necessary clause in any legal system, otherwise it would be too easy to make a law that says, “the laws do not apply to the following people.” Doesn’t the Due Process Clause of the 14th Amendment, or anything similar, imply that the laws aren’t optional depending on who you are?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I wonder if they will remove the "What is the Rule of Law?" question from the citizenship test, now that it no longer applies in the US.

@DewiMorgan I'm sure Democrats would like that.

Well, there's certainly parts of the Constitution that says the laws don't apply universally to all citizens. For the legislative branch, there's the Speech and Debate clause:

[Members of Congress] shall in all Cases, except Treason, Felony and Breach of the Peace, be privileged from Arrest during their Attendance at the Session of their respective Houses, and in going to and returning from the same; and for any Speech or Debate in either House, they shall not be questioned in any other Place.

You evince surprise in your question that it was "legally possible" to make a law which applies unequally, or which some people are explicitly excluded from having to obey. The legal justification for executive privilege comes from the Constitution, not from legislation. But even if it had, this is done constantly. For instance, for most of us it's illegal to stand in the middle of an intersection blocking traffic; but it's not illegal for a police officer to do so while directing traffic. For most of us it's illegal to possess eagle feathers; but this doesn't apply to Native Americans possessing them for use in tribal customs. It's illegal to own various controlled substances, but not if you have a prescription for them. It's illegal to shoot someone, but not in (some cases of) self-defense. Laws without exceptions are the exception.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No, it initially stated the opposite
In its original incarnation the US Constitution established a slave state and clearly differentiated between the two classes of people within its borders - slaves and free citizens. The intention of the fourteenth amendment was to remove this distinction although the proliferation of Jim Crow laws was a side step around it and it was only with the successes of the Civil Rights movement 100 years or so after the amendment that the facts enacted the rhetoric (sort of).
In any event, there has never been any suggestion that the same act by different people may be criminal for one but perfectly legal for another. The obvious examples are soldiers and police officers, they routinely do things that would be crimes if done by someone else. For example, if I pulled on white gloves and started directing traffic, I would rightly be arrested, but a police officer would just be doing their job.
The Constitution defines the operations and limits of government. It in no way suggests that it is not appropriate to have different laws for different people.

Don't forget laws like the 1790 naturalisation act, 1907 "Gentleman Agreement", immigration act of 1927 and Executive Order 9066 - all of which might actually contain passages that were unconstitutional at the time of enactment (esp. reg. Ius Soli)

Re: "there has never been any suggestion that the same act by different people may be criminal for one but perfectly legal for another": I think this says the opposite of what you intended to!

@Trish the question concerns citizens, which those laws do not (and only two of them are actually laws).

Three classes, not two: "free", "slave", and "Indians not taxed".

@Mark: Technically, the three classes for the purpose of Congressional apportionment are "free Persons", "Indians not taxed", and "all other Persons", with the last category implied to be slaves, awkwardly phrased to avoid the embarrassment of using the word "slave".

The three fifths compromise was not about "establishing a slave state". It was about the north wanting to limit the power of slave owners. The constitution was intentionally mute on the topic of slavery, because coming down on either side would alienate either the north or south. The "distiction" between free and slave was only about the census and was designed to limit the congressional power of slave states.

@Mark Whether the constitution established two or three classes of persons for any specific purpose does not detract from the point made by this answer.  But actually neither classification addresses the question because neither Indians not taxed nor "all other persons" were citizens, and the question asks about unequal treatment of citizens.

The decision regarding immunity for a President was not immunity for things a President (or former President) might do in their capacity as a private citizen, but rather what they do in their capacity as the President of the United States (within the defined powers of such.)
The Constitution grants certain powers explicitly to the President. The Supreme Court ruling stated that the President is immune from criminal liability in the exercise of these powers because anything else would violate the Constitution's intended separation of powers. In other words, Congress cannot make a law that makes it a criminal offense for the President to carry out a power granted to the President by the Constitution. That would itself be unconstitutional on the part of Congress and legally void. Congress cannot nullify a Constitutional power of the President simply by passing a law. Changing the President's Constitutional powers would require amending the Constitution, as with changing any other part of the Constitution.
Additionally, Congress may (and does) grant certain powers by law to the executive branch. This is how essentially all federal regulation and federal agencies exist. The President was also held to have criminal immunity from carrying out powers delegate to the President by these acts of Congress. This again prevents political prosecution for a President carrying out the legal duties of their job.
The ruling explicitly held that the President has no criminal immunity for acts outside of their official acts within the defined powers of the President. If the President punches his opponent during a debate, for example, they would have no criminal immunity unless Congress had passed a law granting the President the power to punch their opponent in a debate.
Aside from the President, the Constitution explicitly grants immunity to members of Congress in quite a few situations. Article I, Section 6 says,

The Senators and Representatives [...] shall in all cases, except treason, felony and breach of the peace, be privileged from arrest during their attendance at the session of their respective Houses, and in going to and returning from the same; and for any speech or debate in either House, they shall not be questioned in any other place.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There is not an article in the constitution that requires absolute uniformity from the legal code. Also, in multiple cases, SCOTUS has ruled that some laws don't apply to people in certain situations.

Trump v. United States -- the president can't be criminally punished for things he did as part of his job as president.
Nixon v. Fitzgerals -- the president can't be forced to pay damages for things he did as part of his job as president.
Scott v. Harris -- it is not illegal for a police officer to injure and kill you while doing his job.

Note that I'm oversimplifying here - these examples of immunity have all the logical restrictions you would expect. For example, the illegal thing you are doing must actually be necessary for your job, and it must be part of your job - if a cop beats up his neighbor just because he doesn't like him, that's still illegal.
There are many such other cases where the regular laws do not apply to some group of people. In fact, very few laws apply to everyone - for example, minors get a radically different set of laws. Felons also experience some important differences.
There are certain cases where a very specific group is required to have the same law. For example, article 4 of the constitution says that you can't have different laws for people from one state vs. another. But that is specifically for the case of which state you are from. There are still lots of other groups which are legally allowed to have different laws.

Some people in some situations have immunity. For example people who decide what laws we have, because we want them to create laws that are good for the country, even if that law is not in their personal interest.
Apart from that, most laws apply to non-citizen residents, to visitors like tourists, and to people who are in the USA illegally, so not just tourists.

It is implied.
The classic example is that the president can order an airstrike on a military target. That's patently illegal for people to do, except for people in a position where it is legal to do it as a function of their job.
It would be illegal to drone strike Jim's house as neither Jim nor his house are military targets. Even for the president.
That's basically what the supreme court made a bit more explicit. That there are some things that presidents do as part of their job that by necessity they are immune from and some things that they are not immune from.

The effect of immunity for official presidential acts, however, is to make the president immune to prosecution even for illegal orders issued as commander in chief, including, perhaps, an order to strike Jim's house.

@phoog: Immune to prosecution in court.  POTUS can still be prosecuted in Congress (as part of impeachment hearings).

@BenVoigt yes, I meant to make that point and forgot.  Thanks for bringing it up.  It's not clear to me whether the decision recognizes that the immunity it provides would end with an impeachment and conviction for a given act.  It does mention the impeachment judgment clause, but I haven't yet read the whole decision, so I am not sure that I've seen everything it has to say on the matter.

impeachment isn't prosecution. it's pretty clear that the immunity the court just invented includes immunity after conviction, because otherwise absolute immunity isn't

@phoog Absolute immunity applies only to "criminal prosecution for actions within his [the President's] conclusive and preclusive constitutional authority".

@user76284 ok, but that immunity apparently extends to evidence connected with that authority, and it seems it would exclude such evidence from other proceedings.  I still haven't read the opinion, so I don't know how people are reaching this conclusion, but apparently they are.
